# AndroidJUnit4.class not found on Instrumentation tests

Tags: android, junit, android-testing, android-junit

I'm having trouble with `AndroidJunit4.class` import.
I created the test class in the `androidTest/java/` folder but it seems that the class is not found.

Even if I force the right import it still doesn't work. ( `import android.support.test`).

```
@RunWith(AndroidJunit4.class)
public class RandomTest {

}
```

Here is my gradle :

```
defaultConfig {
 testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

dependencies {
 compile "com.android.support:support-annotations:23.4.0"
 compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0"
 compile 'cat.ereza:customactivityoncrash:1.5.0'
 testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
 androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
 androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test:runner:0.5')
 androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test:rules:0.5')
 androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2')
 androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.2')
 androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:2.2.2')

 testCompile('com.android.support.test:runner:0.5')
 testCompile('com.android.support.test:rules:0.5')
 testCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2')
 testCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.2')
 testCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:2.2.2')

 testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
 testCompile "org.robolectric:robolectric:3.1.1"
}
```

Weird thing is that I can find `AndroidJunit4` file in my project, but in its parent `AndroidJunit4ClassRunner`, `AndroidRunnerParams` class is not resolved even if I also can find the file in my Project.

Comment: Are you also adding `testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"` under defaultConfig?

Comment: Yes I also added it, I forgot to notice it above.

Answer (score 0):

Comment out the annotation

```
//@RunWith(AndroidJunit4.class)
```

In Android Studio, choose "Build > Rebuild Project"

Get the annotation back in again

```
@RunWith(AndroidJunit4.class)
```

ALT-ENTER -> Import class